# how to add scroller in the data table

Tags: c#, html, datatable, bootstrap-4

i have data table while im seeing in mobile some of the columns getting hide. how to make it scrollable so that i can view in mobile also . responsiveness is missing in my datatable.i have added the bootstrap references also

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false
    });
  });
    </script>


                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl No</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Oil Temperature</th>
                                <th>Winding Temperature</th>
                                <th>Ambient Temperature</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.i</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.UpdatedTime</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.Oil_temp</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.winding_temp</td>
                                    <td>@item.value.Ambient_temp</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sl No</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Oil Temperature</th>
                                <th>Winding Temperature</th>
                                <th>Ambient Temperature</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Check [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) props in CSS. You need to set it to `scroll`.

Comment: Have you used bootstrap in the application? That's the answer of your question to implement device neutral web UI.

Comment: yes i have added bootstrap in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
#table-scroll {
width:100%;
height:200;
overflow:auto;  
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
</style>

<div id="table-scroll">
<table>
```

Please Inform if it is Useful .. Thank You..